# Fisheye distortion correction

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, fisheye

I saw on this link http://www.tannerhelland.com/4743/simple-algorithm-correcting-lens-distortion/ an algorithm to cancel Fisheye lens distortion and I tried to implement it in C++ with opencv. The output image is exactly the same as the input image when the parameter strength is close to zero, and I get bad results with higher values. If someone knows what could be the problem (in my code or, more generally, in the algorithm), It would be very helpful. 
Thank you very much.

```
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\calib3d\calib3d.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {

    cout << " Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
    Mat_<Vec3b> eiffel;
    eiffel = imread("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/TestFisheye.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file
    if (!eiffel.data)                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "Input image depth: " << eiffel.depth() << endl;

    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
    imshow("Display window", eiffel);                   // Show our image inside it.

    //waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window

    int halfWidth = eiffel.rows / 2;
    int halfHeight = eiffel.cols / 2;
    double strength = 0.0001;
    double correctionRadius = sqrt(pow(eiffel.rows, 2) + pow(eiffel.cols, 2)) / strength;
    Mat_<Vec3b> dstImage = eiffel;

    int newX, newY;
    double distance; 
    double theta; 
    int sourceX; 
    int sourceY; 
    double r;
    for (int i = 0; i < dstImage.rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dstImage.cols; j++)
        {
            newX = i - halfWidth; 
            newY = j - halfHeight;
            distance = sqrt(pow(newX, 2) + pow(newY, 2));
            r = distance / correctionRadius;
            if (r == 0.0)
                theta = 1;
            else
                theta = atan(r) / r;

            sourceX = round(halfWidth + theta*newX);
            sourceY = round(halfHeight + theta * newY);

            dstImage(i, j)[0] = eiffel(sourceX, sourceY)[0];
            dstImage(i, j)[1] = eiffel(sourceX, sourceY)[1];
            dstImage(i, j)[2] = eiffel(sourceX, sourceY)[2];
        }
    }

    namedWindow("Display window 2", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display window 2", dstImage);                   // Show our image inside it.
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

PS: I' m currently working on the first image posted in the link.

Comment: [This](http://marcodiiga.github.io/radial-lens-undistortion-filtering) might also interest you

Comment: See OpenCV implementation of same algorithm here https://sourcecodezoneseven.blogspot.com/2019/07/simple-algorithm-for-correcting-lens.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues here:

1 - you need to increase the strength from 0.0001 to something more reasonable (try 5).

2 - you are using the same origin and destination matrix. This `Mat_<Vec3b> dstImage = eiffel;` doesn't atually allocate any new memory. `dstImage` is simply a smart pointer to the original image. So when you modify it, you are modifying the source image at the same time. This will give you very poor results. Instead do `Mat_<Vec3b> dstImage = eiffel.clone()`

With these changes I get the following image:
[image]

Not great, but fast & simple at least.

Comment: See OpenCV implementation of same algorithm here https://sourcecodezoneseven.blogspot.com/2019/07/simple-algorithm-for-correcting-lens.html